# remove gif image only from content

Tags: php, regex

Trying to remove only gif image from the content , tried below but that does remove all images

```
  $content = "this is <img src="https://ecwowocc.com/test.gif"/> something with an <img src=https://ecwowocc.com/test.png"/> in it.";
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $content); 
    echo $content;
```

i want to remove only GIF from the content

Comment: you need something which matches the exact text "gif" in the middle of the img tag then. What have you tried so far?

Comment: its 2020 do people still use regex to parse html :/ [see why its not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone You are totally right of course, but in the OP's case, it would be a bit overkill to implement an HTML parser to detect a single self-closing tag like `img`. There are no cases of nested elements possible here and from the question it is not expected that we can have a `>` in the image path.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

`<img[^>]+src=\\?(?:"|')[^.]+\.gif\\?(?:"|')[^>]+\>`

specifics:

- will match src attribute either used with `"` or `'`
- will match if `"` or `'` is escaped or not
- small caution: this regex will not support a `>` character in another attribute of the `img` tag

[see it in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Kb99hO/3)

As suggested by AmigoJack, it can be improved to the form:

`<img[^>]+src=(\\?["'])[^'"]+\.gif\1[^>]*\/?>`

Comment: i have image src <img src="https://sndsds.com/wMaJYa8CFU3JJNVQ76F/giphy.gif" />
so what do change in regrex?

Comment: Why `(?:"|')` and not `["']`? Why only `[^.]` and not `[^"'>]`? Why is `>` escaped? To me this is quite trite. A better regex (not "regrex") is `<img [^>]+src(\\?["'])[^'">]+\.gif\1[^>]*/?>`

Comment: @AmigoJack for the first I reckon it's a bad habit I took, classes are effectively quicker than alternations, for the rest, there are ideas, but for a trite thing your regex is both invalid (`/` needs to be escaped) and [doesn't actually work](https://regex101.com/r/7COeZl/2). I added your suggestions with corrections though.

Comment: No, `/` doesn't **need** to be escaped (only when you use `/` as regex delimiters, but that's not mandatory). Yes, my version didn't work, but [`<img[^>]+src=(["'])\\?[^'">]+\.gif\1[^>]*/?>`](https://regex101.com/r/7COeZl/2) does (even better, because yours would also match `<img src="diff'>` and fail for `<img src="slash" />`. Again: your `\>` makes no sense (neither PHP strings nor regex need it escaped).

Comment: Please be more precise, neither [the original](https://regex101.com/r/H3J4XI/1) not the [updated one](https://regex101.com/r/QuP7w0/1) will match `<img src="one'>`, and we want `<img src="" />` to fail because it's not a .gif. Agreed for the `\>`, the backslash was a leftover from a precedent regex. But actually it's still valid

Answer (score 0):

Try Using str_replace() function

Syntax,

str_replace(search, replace, subject);

```
<?php
  $content = "this is <img src=\"test.gif\"/> something with an <img src=\"test.png\"/> in it.";
  echo str_replace(".gif", ".png", $content);
?>
```

Comment: This will replace all `.gif` image extensions by `.png`, which will not remove the gif images and will most probably lead to images not found icons